# Why/how did I get banned from asking questions on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, meta, help-center, help

I am so confused, I have asked like 5 questions on `programmers.stackexchange.com` / `softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`, and all of them have upvotes. Yet, I logged in a week ago, and now I can't ask a question anymore:

"You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

[image]

Anyone have any idea *why* this might have happened?

My account is here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/101210/alexander-mills

I have a ton of points over at StackOverflow, so the StackExchange network should know that I contribute positively.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223975/alexander-mills

Miffed.
-alex

Comment: Did you click that link in the message?

Comment: yeah I did click that link, I will show a screenshot from that link

Comment: Note that deleted questions also affect your abilities to post new questions.

Comment: the link just leads to this static page: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Comment: You have seven deleted questions, some of them down-voted quite heavily. (And I wouldn't call 4k "a ton of points")

Comment: except the association bonus there is no cross-over of rep and track record across sites.

Comment: I would be willing to bet that 4K puts in me in top 10% of usership, easy

Comment: How did you see the deleted questions? I cannot figure out how to see them or see a count of them - http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/101210/alexander-mills?tab=questions

Comment: ChrisF is a moderator on se.se - so he can see deleted posts there.

Comment: got it thanks, @ChrisF would you mind sending me a copy/paste of the deleted questions? That would be helpful... very curious what they were, probably many were from my early days

Comment: I have 6 deleted questions apparently, and 1 of them is just a duplicate of another. So really it's just 5. And of those 5, only 1 has more than 1 downvote.

Comment: It puts me most likely in top 3% of usership, not just top 10%. Therefore "ton of points" seems more than warranted. In fact, it's 2.25 tons of points, if points were pounds.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Having 2 rep puts you in like the top 20%.  The majority of accounts don't provide even a *single* useful contribution to the site.

Comment: @Servy I am talking about having 4000+ points on SO, ignoring all other SE sites. Aren't there like 40 SE sites? Having 4000+ points on SO is meaningful.

Comment: @AlexanderMills you on [page 767](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2016-11-01/1223975?sort=totalreputation#1223975) on Stack Overflow, quite sure that 767 pages out of 4566 pages of 30 items each is between 16-17% (`(797/4566)*100`). when i change it to [50 items per page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2016-11-01/1223975?sort=totalreputation&pagesize=50) (`(460/2740)*100`) it's the same percentage

Comment: @AlexanderMills I would only like to point out that the histogram that you point to is over six years old and may not be representative of today's data. You may want to find something a bit more up-to-date to point to. (The other one on that page is not much better, as it was posted in 2011.)

Comment: I was going off of a histogram that shows number of people by number of points, but I think the histogram was from 2010, so it's just way too old to reference. Yeah, you beat me to it. I will agree that I am probably top ~15% on SO.

Comment: Also, a question like this is pretty good, and people clearly like discussing it, so why does it get so many downvotes?

Comment: You could just undelete the question that you would find easiest to improve, and then improve it, and then do the same for some or all of the other deleted questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo, if that is true, thanks for that information and I will try that out

Comment: One might be a great chef, with 100000 rep on cooking.SE - that does NOT make him a good programmer, and he can easily ask horrible questions on Stack Overflow and get rightfully question banned. Same goes with all sites: having high reputation in one site means totally nothing for other sites.

Answer (score 13):

You've asked 6 questions that were downvoted and closed and/or deleted:

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309735/best-sitebuilder-to-showcase-software-library
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309736/best-sitebuilder-tool-to-showcase-software-library
3. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/296949/flux-architecture-w-backone-how-to-use-action-creators-for-all-http-responses
4. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294688/avoiding-global-configuration-between-tests-and-server
5. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246482/does-one-really-need-multiple-instances-of-a-class
6. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210223/is-there-a-difference-between-graph-database-such-as-neo4j-and-an-object-databas

(there's another question that was deleted, but wasn't downvoted; that doesn't matter for the purpose of this discussion)

The questions that *haven't* been downvoted have been reasonable; still, based on the number of questions that have done poorly, the system predicts a poor chance of future questions doing well, hence the ban.

See also: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: all I can say is, the banning algorithm is being pretty lame, none of those questions are all that bad.

Comment: to add, while all 6 are deleted they all still add to the penalty

Comment: @AlexanderMills - at least the first two are off topic on all SE sites - they are polls. This kind of question does poorly on the sites and is therefore disallowed.

Comment: The ban should get lifted automatically, as these deleted questions become more and more ancient, IMO

Comment: You get one question every 6 months, regardless of ban status, @Alexander. If those end up being good, the ban eventually goes away.

Comment: thanks for the info, however dismal it may be

Comment: @AlexanderMills Not lame at all. Losing the ability to ask questions because you asked too many bad ones is like losing your drivers license because you crashed too many times and killed too many people. Sure it sucks for *you*, but it's better for the community.

Comment: Right, but this is a debate about how many people you can kill before you lose your license, I am arguing for more people. Especially, if it were a long time ago, when you were an inexperienced driver.